# Build using sources from a duplicate tree

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

GNU Make 3.8.1

I am working on what is basically a plugin for a software product. The plugin is built in a subdirectory of the main product, so the directory structure looks something like:

product
product/src
product/plugin
product/plugin/myPlugin

where "myPlugin" is the name of the plugin I'm working on. What I would like to do, is be able to build myPlugin as well as another version of myPlugin, call it myPlugin-lite. This plugin would have the same sources as myPlugin, but use different flags and defines in the makefiles. The idea was to create a duplicate of the myPlugin tree structure, containing only myPlugin's makefiles, and have it build *using the sources from myPlugin*. So the directory structure would look like:

product
product/src
product/plugin
product/plugin/myPlugin
product/plugin/myPlugin-lite

myPlugin would build and create all its targets within its subdirectory, and myPlugin-lite would build and create all its targets within its subdirectory. I found a few solutions here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/multi-architecture-builds/ and out of these options it seems like the symbolic links would be best, but it still doesn't feel like the "right" way to do this.

My question is, is this the  best/simplest/most maintainable way to do this? If not what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need from `myPlugin` is source files then this is **exactly** what [`VPATH`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search) and [The `vpath` Directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) are for.

> 4.5.1 VPATH: Search Path for All Prerequisites
>
> The value of the make variable VPATH specifies a list of directories that make should search. Most often, the directories are expected to contain prerequisite files that are not in the current directory; however, make uses VPATH as a search list for both prerequisites and targets of rules.
>
> Thus, if a file that is listed as a target or prerequisite does not exist in the current directory, make searches the directories listed in VPATH for a file with that name. If a file is found in one of them, that file may become the prerequisite (see below). Rules may then specify the names of files in the prerequisite list as if they all existed in the current directory. See Writing Recipes with Directory Search.
>
> In the VPATH variable, directory names are separated by colons or blanks. The order in which directories are listed is the order followed by make in its search. (On MS-DOS and MS-Windows, semi-colons are used as separators of directory names in VPATH, since the colon can be used in the pathname itself, after the drive letter.)
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> VPATH = src:../headers
> ```
>
> specifies a path containing two directories, src and ../headers, which make searches in that order.
>
> With this value of VPATH, the following rule,
>
> ```
> foo.o : foo.c
> ```
>
> is interpreted as if it were written like this:
>
> ```
> foo.o : src/foo.c
> ```
>
> assuming the file foo.c does not exist in the current directory but is found in the directory src.

Also see [How Not to Use VPATH](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/) from MadScientist for more discussion about what they aren't for. Though that's largely just a build-up for the multi-architecture-builds paper you already read.

Comment: Is there a way to debug VPATH? Using the -d option for make, I don't see it looking in the directories I'm specifying. Also, when it searches the paths in VPATH, does it expect paths relative to the targets, or paths relative to the makefile? Does it use the stem or the stem with the path? i.e. src/file.c vs file.c.

Comment: I believe the paths are relative to the makefile and that VPATH just adds new "makefile" locations. So a VPATH of `../myPlugin` will make a target of `foo.o: foo.c` be seen as `foo.o: ../myPlugin/foo.c`. If the directories exist then you should see them listed near the end of the `make -qp` output in the `VPATH` section. Do you?

Comment: I added VPATH = ../../../../../plugin/myPlugin/src/lib/blah/ to the makefile in plugin/myPlugin-lite/src/lib/blah/, and when I ran make from that directory I got: '# No vpath search paths.

# No general (VPATH variable) search path.'

Comment: When I set vpath it shows up in the debug output, now to figure out what path it wants...

Comment: Isn't that too many `../`s in that path? Also is this recursive makefiles or just a makefile not in the top directory? The path is likely relative to `$PWD` (which is normally where the makefile itself is but can be different if you are using `make -f some/path/to/Makefile`).

Comment: It's not too many `../`s, we have recursive makefiles. There is a makefile in almost every directory, so you can build from almost anywhere in the tree (building only that part of the tree). Our build rules look like this:    `%.o : $(srcloc)/%.c` where `srcloc` has a default value that can be overridden. This was working really well for what I'm trying to do in makefiles that only build sources in their own directory, but building subdirectories didn't work because of the same issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799855/how-to-include-path-prefix-in-gnu-make-pattern-rule

Comment: Yeah, that `$(srcloc)` thing is going to complicate this. You'd need to dynamically set it to have the correct number of `../` components to cancel out the current relative path.